# Finding the Parent of an Element, then Clicking a Button Child of that Parent in C#/Selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, browser-automation

I am quite stuck while testing a web application. I am trying to check to ensure a class exists - in this case the class of "originalProductPrice" - out of a group of identical looking li items. Only some of them have this class and if one does I want to click the btn-primary (labeled See More below). Essentially what it feels like I need to do is find the originalProductPrice class - walk up to the top li parent and then drill back down to the button to make sure I am clicking the button associated with that class. However, I am lost as to how to do that. My closest attempt so far has been:

```
[When(@"I Click See More on the First Option with An Original Product Price")]
public void WhenIClickSeeMoreOnTheFirstOptionWithAnOriginalProductPrice()
{
    ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> packages = CurrentBrowser.FindElements
        (By.XPath("//span[@class = 'originalProductPrice:first-child']//tr"));
    ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> seeMore = packages.FindElements
        (By.XPath(".//li[@class='btn-primary:first-child']/div"));
    seeMore.Click();
}
```

Below is the corresponding HTML:

```
<li class="span4" id="Tile">
<div class="thumbnail">
    <div id="locationImage">
        <div id="sImage"></div>
    </div>
    <div name="InvokeWhiteSpaceWrap">
        <span id="sName">Name</span>
        <span name="ratings">
            <span id="sMinRating"></span>
            <span id="sMaxRating"></span>
        </span>
        <div id="sDescription">
        </div>
        <table class="table table-condensed table-striped" id="pList">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div name="pNameDiv">
                            Name                                
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="nowrap">
                        <span name="pPrice">
                            <span class="beforePriceCurrency">$</span>
                            180.00
                            <span class="afterPriceCurrency"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span name="originalProductPrice" 
                              class="originalProductPrice">
                            <span class="beforePriceCurrency">$</span>
                            200.00
                            <span class="afterPriceCurrency"></span>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br>
    <a onclick="$.blockUI({ message: $('#waitMessage') });" 
        class="btn btn-block btn-link btn-small">
        More Options Available                                           
    </a>
    <a onclick="$.blockUI({ message: $('#waitMessage') });" 
        class="btn btn-block btn-primary">See More</a>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: for some funny reason, your code was not shown properly, they went so far that some of them could not be seen. I noticed when I attempted to edit your code, I could see everything in the editing mode, not sure if this was a stackoverflow issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following.

```
IWebElement button = CurrentBrowser.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='originalProductPrice']/ancestor::li//a[contains(@class,'btn-primary')]"));
button.Click();
```

The portion of note in this XPath is `/ancestor::li`. The XPath works by first finding the `<span>` element with class equal to "originalProductPrice", then searching for your button from the nearest `<li>` element that is a parent of that span.

Answer (score 2):

Use below mentioned Xpath to locate your element:

```
//table[//span[@class='originalProductPrice']]/following::a[text()='See More']
```

**Explanation :**

```
//table[//span[@class='originalProductPrice']]
```

Locate the `<table>` where it found `class = originalProductPrice` for the `<span>`

```
/following::a[text()='See More']
```

Locate the anchor tag  which follows the above located table.

OR

```
//table[//span[@class='originalProductPrice']]/../following-sibling::a[@class="btn btn-block btn-primary"]
```

OR

```
//span[@class='originalProductPrice']/ancestor::table/following::a[text()='See More']
```

Also there can be different ways to locate the same element. you can go through some tutorial to get the idea about using `following` `contains` `ancestor` `sibling` `parent` etc in xpath. Refer [this](https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html) site or google the same topic.